# Android Explicit Intent code

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, explicit

How can I pass the control from one Activity to another using the explicit Intent?
I had an issue in androidManifest.xmnl as it marked the Mainactivity file As an error.

Comment: paste your manifest here ?

Comment: what do you mean with passing the control from one Activity to another?

Comment: paste complete code so we can help you.

Comment: I just like to take the control from one activity to another without any internal actions..just navigate

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to navigate from one activity to another you can use explicit intent as :

```
Intent next = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this , NextActivity.class);
startActivity(next);
```